# Save image width in global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

```
var first_img = new Image();        
first_img.src = 'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=1bb1862085f1bc99c8eff04a674864838f1c53cb-4772764-images-thumbs&n=13';  
var first_width;
var first_height;

first_img.onload = function(){          
 first_width = first_img.width;     
 first_height = first_img.height;               
}
       
alert(first_width);
```

I need to save `first_width` outsie first_img.onload. Now i get `undefined`

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/pa5n27vq/

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is set inside the onload callback, even if the image was to load instantly, the alert will always run before the image loads. But those variables should work fine once it's loaded. If you just want to test the globals, you could just try manually checking the values of the 2 in the browser console once it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does things in this order:

- set up `var`s
- set up an `onload` handler on your image
- alert `first_width`, which is `undefined` at this point
- once the image loads, set `first_width` to the image's width

Note how the `alert` happens before the image's `onload` handler runs.

The simplest way to alert the width after the image loads, is to put the `alert` inside the `onload` handler.

```
var first_img = new Image();
first_img.src = 'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=1bb1862085f1bc99c8eff04a674864838f1c53cb-4772764-images-thumbs&n=13';  
var first_width;
var first_height;

first_img.onload = function(){
    first_width = first_img.width;
    first_height = first_img.height;
    alert(`this happens second, first_width = ${first_width}`);
}

alert(`this happens first, first_width = ${first_width}`);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tyadspzu/